# Wordpress Post Previous/Next links with image and title only on previous

Tags: wordpress, posts

I'm trying to add images of arrows for previous post and next post which I was able to do but I want the post titles to show only on the previous posts not the next posts.

Here is the code I have -

```
 <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_post_link('%link', ' <img src="/wp-content/themes/azure-basic-child/images/larrow.png" />' , ' %title '); ?></div>

 <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_post_link('%link', ' <img src="/wp-content/themes/azure-basic-child/images/rarrow.png" /> '); ?></div>
```

This is the page - https://lucchesipgh.org/word-of-the-week/

I have the arrows there but not the previous posts titles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `get_previous_post()` and `get_next_post()` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post / https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post).

The functions will return the post object (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).

If you need the title use `echo $post->title` (unfiltered) or `the_title($post->ID)` (filtered). To get the permalink use `echo get_the_permalink($post->ID)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  So how would I add the title part to what I currently have?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here's what I did and it worked -

```
 <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_post_link('%link', ' <img src="/wp-content/themes/azure-basic-child/images/larrow.png" /> %title' ); ?></div>

 <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_post_link('%link', ' <img src="/wp-content/themes/azure-basic-child/images/rarrow.png" /> '); ?></div>
```